# Does the iOS Physics engine use Box2D internally? Can I access it directly?

Tags: ios, ios7, box2d

I accidentally caused an assertion failure while using PhysicsKit in a SpriteKit game today. The log said this:

```
Assertion failed: (area > 1.19209290e-7F), function ComputeCentroid, file /SourceCache/PhysicsKit/PhysicsKit-6.5.4/PhysicsKit/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp, line 122.
```

That's Box2D right there. I didn't know this. Is anyone else aware of this? If yes, **how can I access the Box2D engine directly?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it's safe to say that PhysicsKit is based on Box2D. There is no means of accessing the engine directly right now - here's hoping they will add more fine-grained control in the future.
If you find yourself needing more control than PhysicsKit currently allows, perhaps you could use Box2D and SpriteKit together instead.